# photo upload code does not work and for the code that already worked before

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller, laravel-blade

i need to upload a photo, the file the information comes from the view in an array with more values of other variables, but the upload code is not working. without this code the rest works perfectly, when I add the upload code nothing works.
help please

```
public function CreateProduction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        
        
        $production = new production;
        $production->status = 1;
        $production->done = 0;
        $production->save();
        $production_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
        

        $proposal = proposal::where('id_proposal', $data['id_proposal'])->first();
        $proposal->id_production = $production_id;
        $proposal->save();
        $proposedphases = $proposal->proposed_phases()->get();
        

        foreach($proposedphases as $proposedphase)
            {
                $this->validate($request, [
                    'select_file'  => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif|max:200000'
                   ]); 
              
                   $image = $request->file('select_file');
              
                   $new = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                   
              
                   $image->move(public_path('images'), $image);

                $productionphase = new production_phases;
                
                   $productionphase->photo = $new;
                $color_cap_out = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'cap_out'])->first();
                    {
                        $productionphase->cap_out_id = $color_cap_out['id_color'];
                        $productionphase->cap_out_name = $color_cap_out['name'];
                        $productionphase->cap_out_code = $color_cap_out['code'];
                    }
                $color_cap_in = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'cap_in'])->first();
                    {
                        $productionphase->cap_in_id = $color_cap_in['id_color'];
                        $productionphase->cap_in_name = $color_cap_in['name'];
                        $productionphase->cap_in_code = $color_cap_in['code'];
                    }
                $color_cord = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'cord'])->first();
                    {
                        $productionphase->cord_id = $color_cord['id_color'];
                        $productionphase->cord_name = $color_cord['name'];
                        $productionphase->cord_code = $color_cord['code'];
                    }
                $color_ribe_corp = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'ribe_corp'])->first();
                    {
                        $productionphase->ribe_corp_id = $color_ribe_corp['id_color'];
                        $productionphase->ribe_corp_name= $color_ribe_corp['name'];
                        $productionphase->ribe_corp_code = $color_ribe_corp['code'];
                    }
                $color_ribe_arm = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'ribe_arm'])->first();
                    {
                        $productionphase->ribe_arm_id = $color_ribe_arm['id_color'];
                        $productionphase->ribe_arm_name = $color_ribe_arm['name'];
                        $productionphase->ribe_arm_code = $color_ribe_arm['code'];
                    }
                $color_bibo = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'bibo'])->first();
                    {
                        $productionphase->bibo_id = $color_bibo['id_color'];
                        $productionphase->bibo_name = $color_bibo['name'];
                        $productionphase->bibo_code = $color_bibo['code'];
                    }
                $color_zip = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'zip'])->first();
                    {
                        $productionphase->zip_id = $color_zip['id_color'];
                        $productionphase->zip_name = $color_zip['name'];
                        $productionphase->zip_code = $color_zip['code'];
                    }
                $color_mola = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'mola'])->first();
                    {
                        $productionphase->mola_id = $color_mola['id_color'];
                        $productionphase->mola_name = $color_mola['name'];
                        $productionphase->mola_code = $color_mola['code'];
                    }
                
                if($data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'arm'] == 0)
                    {
                        $productionphase->arm_name = 'normal';
                    }
                if($data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'arm'] == 1)
                    {
                        $productionphase->arm_name = 'reglan';
                    }
                $productionphase->material = $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'material'];
                $productionphase->id_production = $production_id;
                $productionphase->id_proposedphase = $proposedphase['id_proposedphase'];
                
                   
                $productionphase->save();
                $productionphase_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
                 
                if ( $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'corp_color_1'] !=0)

                    {
                        $color_1 = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'corp_color_1'])->first();
                        $production_phase_colors = new production_phase_colors;
                        $production_phase_colors->part = 0;
                        $production_phase_colors->id_color = $color_1['id_color'];
                        $production_phase_colors->name = $color_1['name'];
                        $production_phase_colors->code = $color_1['code'];
                        $production_phase_colors->id_productionphase = $productionphase_id; 
                        $production_phase_colors->save();
                    }
                
                if ( $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'corp_color_2'] !=0)

                    {
                        $color_2 = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'corp_color_2'])->first();
                        $production_phase_colors = new production_phase_colors;
                        $production_phase_colors->part = 0;
                        $production_phase_colors->id_color = $color_2['id_color'];
                        $production_phase_colors->name = $color_2['name'];
                        $production_phase_colors->code = $color_2['code'];
                        $production_phase_colors->id_productionphase = $productionphase_id; 
                        $production_phase_colors->save();
                    }

                if ( $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'corp_color_3'] !=0)

                    {
                        $color_3 = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'corp_color_3'])->first();
                        $production_phase_colors = new production_phase_colors;
                        $production_phase_colors->part = 0;
                        $production_phase_colors->id_color = $color_3['id_color'];
                        $production_phase_colors->name = $color_3['name'];
                        $production_phase_colors->code = $color_3['code'];
                        $production_phase_colors->id_productionphase = $productionphase_id; 
                        $production_phase_colors->save();
                    }

                if ( $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'arm_color_1'] !=0)

                    {
                        $color_1 = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'arm_color_1'])->first();
                        $production_phase_colors = new production_phase_colors;
                        $production_phase_colors->part = 1;
                        $production_phase_colors->id_color = $color_1['id_color'];
                        $production_phase_colors->name = $color_1['name'];
                        $production_phase_colors->code = $color_1['code'];
                        $production_phase_colors->id_productionphase = $productionphase_id; 
                        $production_phase_colors->save();
                    }
                
                if ( $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'arm_color_2'] !=0)

                    {
                        $color_2 = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'arm_color_2'])->first();
                        $production_phase_colors = new production_phase_colors;
                        $production_phase_colors->part = 1;
                        $production_phase_colors->id_color = $color_2['id_color'];
                        $production_phase_colors->name = $color_2['name'];
                        $production_phase_colors->code = $color_2['code'];
                        $production_phase_colors->id_productionphase = $productionphase_id; 
                        $production_phase_colors->save();
                    }
                    
                if ( $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'arm_color_3'] !=0)

                    {
                        $color_3 = color::where('id_color', $data[$proposedphase->id_proposedphase.'arm_color_3'])->first();
                        $production_phase_colors = new production_phase_colors;
                        $production_phase_colors->part = 1;
                        $production_phase_colors->id_color = $color_3['id_color'];
                        $production_phase_colors->name = $color_3['name'];
                        $production_phase_colors->code = $color_3['code'];
                        $production_phase_colors->id_productionphase = $productionphase_id; 
                        $production_phase_colors->save();
                    }

                $proposedphasesizes = $proposedphase->proposedphasesizes()->get();

                foreach($proposedphasesizes as $proposedphasesize)
                    {
                        $productionphasesize = new production_phase_size;
                        $productionphasesize->id_size = $proposedphasesize['id_size'];
                        $productionphasesize->name = $proposedphasesize['name'];
                        $productionphasesize->quantity = $proposedphasesize['quantity'];
                        $productionphasesize->done = 0;
                        $productionphasesize->id_productionphase = $productionphase_id;
                        $productionphasesize->save();
                        
                    }

                
            }
            $production = production::where('id_production', $production_id)->first();

                    $logs = new logs;
                    $logs->id_user = Auth::user()->id_user;
                    $logs->name = Auth::user()->name;
                    $logs->description = "criada nova produção";
                    $logs->save();

            return view('admin.production.list_productions', compact('production'));  
    }
```

here is the complete controller for analysis as requested, I continue to say that without the upload code that is right after opening the foreach the rest works perfectly, but with this piece it stops working

Comment: Please post the complete controller method code to get the context. Truncated code doesn't help understanding the context completely

Comment: @Donkarnash edited the post with the full code

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code for file uploading.

```
$image = $request->file('select_file');
$new = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
$image->move(public_path('images'), $new);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was with the way you were trying to save the uploaded file - parameters to the move() method

Try the below

```php
    public function CreateProduction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $production = production::create(['status' => 1, 'done' => 0]);

        $proposal = proposal::where('id_proposal', $data['id_proposal'])->first();

        $proposal->id_production = $production->id_production;
        $proposal->save();
        $proposedphases = $proposal->proposed_phases;

        foreach ($proposedphases as $proposedphase) {           
            $proposedphaseId = $proposedphase->id_proposedphase;

            $productionphaseData = array_merge(
                ['photo' => $this->checkPresenceAndSaveImage('select_file', $request)],
                $this->getCapOutData($data[$proposedphaseId . 'cap_out']),
                $this->getCapInData($data[$proposedphaseId . 'cap_in']),
                $this->getCordData($data[$proposedphaseId . 'cord']),
                $this->getRibeCorpData($data[$proposedphaseId . 'ribe_corp']),
                $this->getRibeArmData($data[$proposedphaseId . 'ribe_arm']),
                $this->getColorBiboData($data[$proposedphaseId . 'bibo']),
                $this->getColorZipData($data[$proposedphaseId . 'zip']),
                $this->getColorMolaData($data[$proposedphaseId . 'mola'])
            );

            if ($data[$proposedphaseId . 'arm'] == 0) {
                $productionphaseData['arm_name'] = 'normal';
            }
            if ($data[$proposedphaseId . 'arm'] == 1) {
                $productionphaseData['arm_name'] = 'reglan';
            }
            $productionphaseData['material']         = $data[$proposedphaseId . 'material'];
            $productionphaseData['id_production']    = $production->id_production;
            $productionphaseData['id_proposedphase'] = $proposedphase['id_proposedphase'];

            $productionphase = production_phases::create($productionphaseData);

            $this->checkAndCreateCorpColors($proposedphaseId, $productionphase->id, $data);

            $this->checkAndCreateArmColors($proposedphaseId, $productionphase->id, $data);

            $this->createProductionPhaseSizes($proposedphase, $productionphase->id);
        }
        

        $logs              = new logs;
        $logs->id_user     = Auth::user()->id_user;
        $logs->name        = Auth::user()->name;
        $logs->description = 'criada nova produção';
        $logs->save();

        return view('admin.production.list_productions', compact('production'));
    }

    protected function checkPresenceAndSaveImage(string $attribute, Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile($attribute) && $request->file($attribute)->isValid()) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                $attribute  => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif|max:200000'
            ]);

            $image = $request->file($attribute);

            $path = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $image->move(public_path('images'), $path);

            return $path;
        }
    }

    protected function getCapOutData($idColor)
    {
        $color_cap_out = color::where('id_color', $idColor)->first();

        return [
            'cap_out_id'   => $color_cap_out['id_color'],
            'cap_out_name' => $color_cap_out['name'],
            'cap_out_code' => $color_cap_out['code'],
        ];
    }

    protected function getCapInData($idColor)
    {
        $color_cap_out = color::where('id_color', $idColor)->first();

        return [
            'cap_out_id'   => $color_cap_out['id_color'],
            'cap_out_name' => $color_cap_out['name'],
            'cap_out_code' => $color_cap_out['code'],
        ];
    }

    protected function getCordData($idColor)
    {
        $color_cord = color::where('id_color', $idColor)->first();

        return [
            'cord_id'   => $color_cord['id_color'],
            'cord_name' => $color_cord['name'],
            'cord_code' => $color_cord['code'],
        ];
    }

    protected function getRibeCorpData($idColor)
    {
        $color_ribe_corp = color::where('id_color', $idColor)->first();

        return [
            'ribe_corp_id'   => $color_ribe_corp['id_color'],
            'ribe_corp_name' => $color_ribe_corp['name'],
            'ribe_corp_code' => $color_ribe_corp['code'],
        ];
    }

    protected function getRibeArmData($idColor)
    {
        $color_ribe_arm = color::where('id_color', $idColor)->first();

        return [
            'ribe_arm_id'   => $color_ribe_arm['id_color'],
            'ribe_arm_name' => $color_ribe_arm['name'],
            'ribe_arm_code' => $color_ribe_arm['code'],
        ];
    }

    protected function getColorBiboData($idColor)
    {
        $color_bibo = color::where('id_color', $idColor)->first();

        return [
            'bibo_id'   => $color_bibo['id_color'],
            'bibo_name' => $color_bibo['name'],
            'bibo_code' => $color_bibo['code'],
        ];
    }

    protected function getColorZipData($idColor)
    {
        $color_zip = color::where('id_color', $idColor)->first();

        return [
            'zip_id'   => $color_zip['id_color'],
            'zip_name' => $color_zip['name'],
            'zip_code' => $color_zip['code'],
        ];
    }

    protected function getColorMolaData($idColor)
    {
        $color_mola = color::where('id_color', $idColor)->first();

        return [
            'mola_id'   => $color_mola['id_color'],
            'mola_name' => $color_mola['name'],
            'mola_code' => $color_mola['code'],
        ];
    }

    protected function checkAndCreateCorpColors($proposedphaseId, $productionphaseId, array $data)
    {
        $colors = collect(['corp_color_1', 'corp_color_2', 'corp_color_3']);
        $keys   = $colors->map(fn ($suffix) => $proposedphaseId . $suffix)->values();

        $keys->each(function ($key) use ($productionphaseId, $data) {
            if ($data[$key] != 0) {
                $color = color::where('id_color', $data[$key])->first();

                production_phase_colors::create([
                    'part'               => 0,
                    'id_color'           => $color['id_color'],
                    'name'               => $color['name'],
                    'code'               => $color['code'],
                    'id_productionphase' => $productionphaseId,
                ]);
            }
        });
    }

    protected function checkAndCreateArmColors($proposedphaseId, $productionphaseId, array $data)
    {
        $colors = collect(['arm_color_1', 'arm_color_2', 'arm_color_3']);
        $keys   = $colors->map(fn ($suffix) => $proposedphaseId . $suffix)->values();

        $keys->each(function ($key) use ($productionphaseId, $data) {
            if ($data[$key] != 0) {
                $color = color::where('id_color', $data[$key])->first();

                production_phase_colors::create([
                    'part'               => 1,
                    'id_color'           => $color['id_color'],
                    'name'               => $color['name'],
                    'code'               => $color['code'],
                    'id_productionphase' => $productionphaseId,
                ]);
            }
        });
    }

    protected function createProductionPhaseSizes($proposedphase, $productionphaseId)
    {
        $proposedphasesizes = $proposedphase->proposedphasesizes()->get();

        foreach ($proposedphasesizes as $proposedphasesize) {
            production_phase_size::create([
                    'id_size'            => $proposedphasesize['id_size'],
                    'name'               => $proposedphasesize['name'],
                    'quantity'           => $proposedphasesize['quantity'],
                    'done'               => 0,
                    'id_productionphase' => $productionphaseId,
                ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Donkarnash where does this value inserted in the string $attribute come from? protected function checkPresenceAndSaveImage(string $attribute, Request $request)

Comment: That is the request attribute containing the file as in `select_file` in this case

Comment: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_productionphase' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `production_phase_colors` (`part`, `id_color`, `name`, `code`, `id_productionphase`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (0, 1, Preto, #000000, ?, 2020-12-05 16:27:05, 2020-12-05 16:27:05))" I can't understand where this error comes from, can you verify?

Comment: You may have to debug `checkAndCreateCorpColors` and `checkAndCreateArmColors` using `dd($productionphaseId)` to check if you are receiving a null value. You must also check the `production_phase_colors` model's $fillable array contains `id_productionphase`

Comment: almost everything is working except the upload part, neither the file goes to the folder nor the name is saved in the database

Comment: Try a `dd($request->file->getClientOriginalName()` after validation in the `checkPresenceAndSaveImage` to see if the validation passes

Comment: everything runs normally, as before and there is no upload